# windows cmd dos not show complete output in a text file

Tags: windows, cmd, io-redirection

if I open windows cmd and type this command:
copy D:\1.txt C:
then I see this result:
Access is denied.
0 file(s) copied.

but with this command:
copy D:\1.txt C:\ > d:\output.txt
output text file shows only this :
0 file(s) copied.

why "Access is denied." is not in output.txt? and how could I have complete output in text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting a command's output to a file via `> somefile.txt` only redirects the data written to "standard output" stream to the file, it does *not* include data written  to "standard error" stream, which is where the "Access is denied." message is written in your case. To capture all output, you need to append `2>&1` to the end of the command, e.g.:

```
copy D:\1.txt C:\ > d:\output.txt 2>&1
```

This can be understood as an instruction to send data written to standard error (stream 2) to standard output (stream 1).

You can also redirect standard error to a different file to standard output with e.g.:

```
copy D:\1.txt C:\ > d:\output.txt 2> d:\errors.txt
```